# Continuous solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to find a continuous solution to the ODE:

$$(1+x^{2})y' +2xy = f(x)$$
with the intial condition $y(0)=0$,
and where

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
x & 0 \leq x<1 \\
-x & x \geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
I split up this question into cases. For case 1, $f(x)=x$ and case 2 $f(x)=-x$.

I then solved the ODE for each separate case.

**Case 1**

I solved using integrating factors to get: $$y_1=\frac{x^2}{2(1+x^2)}.$$

**Case 2**

I used the same method to get: $$y_2=\frac{-x^2}{2(1+x^2)}.$$

For both the cases my c-value calculated from the initial condition was 0.

However when I look at the graph of these two functions for the interval $0$ to infinity, they are discontinuous. I don't think I did the ODE wrong as I double checked. Whats up here?

If I use the condition of $y_1(1)=y_2(1)$ Then I will get $y_1(1)=1/4$. However just looking at the equation of y2, it doesn't seem like its possible to get a positive number.

Answer (score 1):

When you integrate case 2 you should not use the condition $y_2(0)=0$ but instead $y_2(1)=y_1(1)$ (where $y_1(1)$ comes from the solution of case 1).
There is then a constant of integration which comes into play.